# Multiple ports for multiple subdirectories within the same website in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, port

I have a IIS-based website, that needs to have the following redirection enabled:

Root directory accessible through :403 only - which is not a big deal.

But whenever a user enters the site using the standard, unencrypted :80, I need to have him redirected to one of subdirectories within the website. 
Preferably, I'd like to keep the address displayed to the user the same in both cases (save the http(s)):

h-t-t-p-s://some.domain.com/ -> secure content from /

h-t-t-p://some.domain.com/ -> not-so-secure content from a subdirectory

Is this kind of redirection possible with IIS? (I know this can be achieved the other way around - that is by forcing secure communication for a subdirectory)

Thanks.

Comment: @Kn43: is the redirect always to the same "non-secure" subdirectory, or can that vary?

Answer (score 2):

With IIS 7.5 and **[URL Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/)** module this can be done easily enough. The configuration for it can be a bit tricky but well worth the exersice. We use it for bouncing between servers and sites across our internal network easily enough.

In this case you will create two sites, one which is HTTPS only and another which is only HTTP. Bind both to the same virtual host name and it should run fine. We did something similiar after renaming a site and moving it around.

Comment: +1 for "interanal network".  ;)